# Do flows and processes get converted to apex behind the scenes?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, process-builder

Do flows and processes get converted to apex after they are saved and activated? ..or does Salesforce have another way of interpreting them?

Comment: There must be a layer deeper than Apex that runs the apex code and looks at limits etc. Pretty sure that runs in Java. My guess would be there's another 'engine' in that layer written in Java thats run Flows. I'm just kinda guessing though. Converting the flows into Apex seems like too much of a pita for them to have gone in that direction.

Comment: I'm guessing it does get translated into apex. The advantage being that they've already done all the work to create a save and stable programming language for their platform once and don't need to do it again.

Comment: Hi codeulike, Kasper, thanks for the replies. It would be great to understand how it works under the hood. I find when I view process builders in git, the code is very verbose. If they are translated into apex, I can't help but think the code must be very long winded and slow compared to well written apex. If I find out I will repost here.